# How to install test command line

Tags: powershell, makefile, mingw

I'm trying to use `test` command, but it does not exists in my system (Windows 8).

```
test -d $(build)
```

How can I install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
IF exist myDirName ( echo myDirName exists ) ELSE ( mkdir myDirName && echo myDirName created)
```

Source => [Here](https://superuser.com/a/219055)

Comment: I have a makefile, and i'm trying to check if a directory exists using "test" command. But my system does not have it.

Comment: Cygwin was maybe a bad idea, here i found someone with similar problem, tell me if it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell you can use the [`Test-Path`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849776.aspx) cmdlet to check for existence of a folder:

```
Test-Path -PathType Container -LiteralPath 'C:\some\folder'
```